# pip install yotta --user unable to find pyocd/_version.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip, python-2.x

I have encountered an error when installing yotta:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/tmp/pip-install-t_jfni1z/pyOCD/
```

The complete error message goes on and on forever and eventually leads to this:

```
File "/tmp/pip-install-t_jfni1z/pyOCD/.eggs/setuptools_scm-3.1.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools_scm/__init__.py", line 72, in dump_version
    with open(target, "w") as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pyocd/_version.py'
```

I have tried to reinstall pyocd, and pip, and python without any success. The error for `pip install pyocd --user` goes as follows:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pyocd/_version.py'
```

Pretty much exactly the same error message, which led me to believe that I may have broke pip.

I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04 and python 2.7.

Is there a way for me to fix this without reinstalling the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bug in the package: https://github.com/mbedmicro/pyOCD/issues/442